# Having issues when attempting to declare constant variable in arduino

Tags: arduino, constants, arduino-c++

I am making a fairly simple script for sound on my arduino. Here's my script:

```
#include <digitalWriteFast.h>

struct AudioHandler {
  //Alter these as you require
  const int pin = 2;
  float frequency = 1;
  float dutyCycle = 1;
    
  //These are internal variables that you shouldn't touch
  unsigned long prevMicros = 0;
  bool onHalf = true;  //This just asks which half of the wave the sound is on
  
  //This just checks the time and asks if it should switch to the other half of the wave
  void updateSound() {
    if ((micros() - prevMicros > (1000000 / frequency) * dutyCycle) && (onHalf)) {
      prevMicros = micros();
      onHalf = false;
      
      digitalWriteFast(pin,false);
    } else if ((micros() - prevMicros > (1000000 / frequency) * (1 - dutyCycle)) && (!onHalf)) {
      prevMicros = micros();
      onHalf = true;
      
      digitalWriteFast(pin,true);
    }
  }
};

AudioHandler test_1;
AudioHandler test_2;
AudioHandler test_3;
AudioHandler test_4;

void setup() {
  pinModeFast(3,OUTPUT); test_1.frequency = 65.41; test_1.dutyCycle = 0.5;
  pinModeFast(4,OUTPUT); test_2.frequency = 82.41; test_2.dutyCycle = 0.5;
  pinModeFast(5,OUTPUT); test_3.frequency = 98.00; test_3.dutyCycle = 0.5;
  pinModeFast(6,OUTPUT); test_4.frequency = 130.81; test_4.dutyCycle = 0.5;

  //I need to set the pin, but couldn't figure out how to do it in struct declaration
  //Also, this 
  int *pinPointer_1; pinPointer_1 = &test_1.pin; *pinPointer_1 = 3;
  int *pinPointer_2; pinPointer_2 = &test_2.pin; *pinPointer_2 = 4;
  int *pinPointer_3; pinPointer_3 = &test_3.pin; *pinPointer_3 = 5;
  int *pinPointer_4; pinPointer_4 = &test_4.pin; *pinPointer_4 = 6;
}

void loop() {
  test_1.updateSound();
  test_2.updateSound();
  test_3.updateSound();
  test_4.updateSound();
}
```

Effectively my script SHOULD work fine, but the arduino IDE is complaining:

```
Warning: Board breadboard:avr:atmega328bb doesn't define a 'build.board' preference. Auto-set to: AVR_ATMEGA328BB
C:\Users\aj200\Documents\GitHub\My-Projects\My-Projects\Active Projects\Sound_PWM_Help\Sound_PWM_Help.ino: In member function 'updateSound':

Sound_PWM_Help:19:7: error: call to 'NonConstantUsed' declared with attribute error: 

       digitalWriteFast(pin,false);

       ^

Sound_PWM_Help:24:7: error: call to 'NonConstantUsed' declared with attribute error: 

       digitalWriteFast(pin,true);

       ^

lto-wrapper.exe: fatal error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc returned 1 exit status

compilation terminated.

c:/program files (x86)/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: error: lto-wrapper failed

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
call to 'NonConstantUsed' declared with attribute error:
```

In theory, this should be complete and functional. HOWEVER, for some reason the arduino compiler is saying that the variable "pin" is not constant (digitalWriteFast(pin,state) requires constant value annoyingly). What am I missing here?

Thanking you in advance,
Andrey

Comment: Move your function out of the `struct`,  it should be just a function pointer in the `struct`.

Comment: You can set constant member in the constructors initializer list. If it's not enough then as a template parameter.

Comment: If it's the same library as I found, it's just bunch of macro definitions, and in this case nothing helps, you have to have its own code for each pin. Or skip it and use direct port manipulation

Comment: Btw, why are you bother with it? That floats possibly takes so much time so it won't matter if your writes takes 1 cycle (direct access)  or 60+ (standard digitalWrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a struct constructor to assign the pins. Then a `setup` method could define them as pins using `pinModeFast()`

This is my take on this. Compiled successfully for Arduino Uno and Leonardo but untested for now. To me, it looks cleaner and easier to follow and grow

```
#include <digitalWriteFast.h>

struct AudioHandler {
  //Alter these as you require
  int _pin;
  float frequency;
  float dutyCycle;

  AudioHandler(int pin){
    
    _pin = pin;
    
    }

  //These are internal variables that you shouldn't touch
  unsigned long prevMicros = 0;
  bool onHalf = true;  //This just asks which half of the wave the sound is on

  //This just checks the time and asks if it should switch to the other half of the wave
  void updateSound() {
    if ((micros() - prevMicros > (1000000 / frequency) * dutyCycle) && (onHalf)) {
      prevMicros = micros();
      onHalf = false;

      digitalWriteFast(_pin, LOW);    // Changed from false
    } else if ((micros() - prevMicros > (1000000 / frequency) * (1 - dutyCycle)) && (!onHalf)) {
      prevMicros = micros();
      onHalf = true;

      digitalWriteFast(_pin, HIGH);  // Changed from true
    }
  }

  void setup(int freq, int duty){
    
    pinModeFast(_pin, OUTPUT);

    frequency = freq;
    dutyCycle = duty;
    
    
    }
};

// Instantiate your audio handlers passing the pin number according to the constructor

AudioHandler test_1 = AudioHandler(3);
AudioHandler test_2 = AudioHandler(4);
AudioHandler test_3 = AudioHandler(5);
AudioHandler test_4 = AudioHandler(6);

void setup() {
      
  // Set them up passing frequency and duty cycle

  test_1.setup(65.41,0.5);   
  test_2.setup(82.41, 0.5);   
  test_3.setup(98.00, 0.5);   
  test_4.setup(130.81,0.5);

}

void loop() {
  test_1.updateSound();
  test_2.updateSound();
  test_3.updateSound();
  test_4.updateSound();
}
```